# How to request contact in C# Telegram Bot API

Tags: c#, .net, telegram-bot, newtonscript

I want to make a contact request using a keyboard button in Telegram Bot API for C#. I know I have to do this with the `request_contact` method. But I did not find any source that would explain this in C#. (All resources were related to Python and PHP)
Please explain this in C# language.
Thankful

Comment: SO is not a tutorial site. This question is far too broad.

Comment: @itsme86 I didn't ask to learn. I just want to see an example of this command in C #

Comment: You and I have different interpretations of the word "explain" I guess. No one wants to help someone that just wants things given to them. You *should* want to learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ReplyKeyboardMarkup` with `KeyboardButton` that requests Contact and if the button was pressed telegam will let user send a contact.

And to show the keyboard, you must use it in `SendTextMessageAsync` as parameter like this:

```cs
private static async void Bot_OnMessage(MessageEventArgs e)
{
    // Defining Keyboard button that requests a contact
    KeyboardButton button = KeyboardButton.WithRequestContact("Send contact");  // Right here, the string defines what text appears on the button

    //Defining Keyboard that contains the button
    ReplyKeyboardMarkup keyboard = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup(button);

    // Send keyboard with message!
    // https://github.com/TelegramBots/Telegram.Bot/blob/master/src/Telegram.Bot/TelegramBotClient.cs#L506
    await Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(e.Message.Chat.Id, "Please send contact", replyMarkup:  keyborad);
}
```